# shrink knitr output to multiple columns

Tags: knitr

I am providing a very simple example here. In my dataset, I have 50+ names in column. I get annoyed by the fact that colnames() output takes 50+ lines too! Is it possible to divide the output over multiple columns? Just by using some simple parameters to add to chunk. So my pdf documents are shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<>>=
library(ggplot2)
colnames(diamonds)
@
\end{document}
```

Sample Output

```
"carat"
"cut"
"color"
"clarity"
"depth"
"table"
"price"
"x"
"y"
"z"
```

Answer (score 2):

While this question would get a better answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r   However, try this for a vertical list

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
cat(colnames(mtcars),sep="\n")
@
\end{document}
```

I am still considering how to eliminate the pesky ##s

Answer (score 1):

Upon the answer of R. Schumacher, if you show the ouput of the chunk  `'asis'` (as LaTeX text)  you can use the LaTeX `\\` as separator, and format the ouput in a `'multicols` environment. This way there are no pesky ##s `;)`

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,paperwidth=8cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
<<results='hide'>>=
cat(colnames(mtcars),sep="\\\\")
@
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\noindent
<<echo=F,results='asis'>>=
cat(colnames(mtcars),sep="\\\\")
@
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent +1.  I had tried the 'asis' option but didn't realize I could use  "sep="\\\\" to solve the rest of the issue.   I recommend talharish accept you answer.  I will now go to bed very happy as I have learned something new.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Happy that this help. `:)`  but your solved the main part.