# Is there any tool/framework to convert R code into Latex?

Tags: algorithms, code, r, conversion

I have a lot of code from R, and I'm working on a research project where I need to write down the pseudocode, is there any way to convert these codes into latex?

Comment: R code is different from pseudocode, because it is real code. If you want to write pseudocode then you cannot convert it but you need to write the pseudocode from scratch, writing down only the important steps of your algorithm and leaving out all practical implementation details. For such a task you can use packages like [algorithm2e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) or [algorithmicx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). If you want to print actual code then you can use [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted).

Comment: Both can be useful (pseudocode and real code), but by definition you cannot convert one into the other.

Comment: Pretty good answer, thank you @Marijn

Comment: Why pseudocode? You can write real code in LaTeX, and show it highlighted and/or execute it.  Do you know knitr? A simple example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240489/11604)

Comment: @Fran good tip! In some cases can be applied, but for mine the code is very big and for those who don't know R it's harder to understand than pseudocode.

Comment: @FelipeAugusto As said,  you can show code without evaluating it, so it could be also a not working code, or it can be a working code but show nothing, or all the code, or only some lines of the working code, and show the outputs or hide also even when it is evaluated. Therefore, in which situation cannot be applied?

Comment: Well, it can be applied, what I mean is that it would be harder for someone who doesn't know R to understand, this is what I meant by "can't be applied in some cases".